# How to store contract state on multiple blocks?

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment, gas, blocks

Eth blocks have a clear block size and gas limit (of 30,000,000).

Some contract states must require more memory than the defined block size, right?

Now my question: can the contract state be saved on multiple blocks? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but you have to use non-traditional structures.  One structure I've used in the past is the fallback proxy.  So you have a list of functions in Contract A (main contract), B, and C.  If you call A with a function not in A, it does a delegate call to B or C.  Now you have more functionality in your contract (just be careful to keep storage the same in each contract).

Comment: Riight, how come I didn't think about it. Do you have a useful resource to read about this further?

Comment: not really unfortunately, just a bunch of delegate proxy contracts: https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/proxy_delegate.html.